# How can i use the group_concat() function in a group sql

Tags: php, mysql

My question is how Am I going to add the query `group_concat()` to my original query?

Here is my original sql:

```
select *
from info
join crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id
join crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id 
where crew_rank in ('1','2','3') and crew_status = '$crew_status' 
and doc_type in ('1','2') and vessel = '$vessel_name' 
and date_issue in (
    select max( date_issue ) 
    from crew_documents_table
    where crew_documents_table.document_crew_id = info.id
)
```

and i want to add a `group_concat()` function in it like this:

```
SELECT document_crew_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(doc_number) as document_number, 
GROUP_CONCAT(date_issue) as date_issued, 
GROUP_CONCAT(date_expiry) as date_expired, 
GROUP_CONCAT(place_of_issue) as place_issued 
from crew_documents_table group by document_crew_id
```

and this is how i get the record from the query:

```
<td><?php if($row['doc_type'] == '1') { echo "$doc_number"; } ?></td>
<td><?php if($row['doc_type'] == '1') { echo "$date_issue"; } ?></td>
<td><?php if($row['doc_type'] == '1') { echo "$date_expiry"; } ?></td>
<td><?php if($row['doc_type'] == '1') { echo "$place_of_issue"; } ?></td>
<td><?php if($row['doc_type'] == '2') { echo "$doc_number"; } ?></td>
<td><?php if($row['doc_type'] == '2') { echo "$doc_number"; } ?></td>
<td><?php if($row['doc_type'] == '2') { echo "$doc_number"; } ?></td>
<td><?php if($row['doc_type'] == '2') { echo "$doc_number"; } ?></td>
```

Comment: what's your question .? you have errors? .. wrong result? no result?

Comment: i will edit. sorry if it's unclear. my question is how im i going to add the query group_concat() sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just change * with you  columns and add the proper group by

```
  select
  document_crew_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(doc_number) as document_number, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(date_issue) as date_issued, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(date_expiry) as date_expired, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(place_of_issue) as place_issued 
  from info join crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id 
  join crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id 
  where crew_rank in ('1','2','3') and crew_status = '$crew_status' 
  and doc_type in ('1','2') and vessel = '$vessel_name' 
  and date_issue in (select max( date_issue ) 
  from crew_documents_table 
  where crew_documents_table.docume
```